# Adobe AIR TOUCH_END event not being dispatched

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

In my app i have a component with 3 event listeners - for TOUCH_BEGIN, TOUCH_MOVE and TOUCH_END. But TOUCH_END event is not always dispatched for some reason.

I am testing on iPod touch 4th gen and using AIR 3.8 SDK.

EDIT:
solution is to listen to touch_roll_out and touch_roll_over.
in some cases it will replace the touch_end events. Read more in the official documentation

Comment: showing your code might help

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a classic? TOUCH_END (and MOUSE_UP) should be dispatched from the DisplayObject in(over) which it happened. If it's not being dispatched when you moved away from the Object with the listener added - this could be your issue.

try `stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd)` rather than `this.addEventListener` instead.

If you only need to track single TouchEvents you would be well advised to use MouseEvents by specifying MultitouchInputMode.NONE instead - MouseEvents are known to perform a lot better in terms of CPU usage.

You could use `this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RELEASE_OUTSIDE, onTouchEnd);` in this case. RELEASE_OUTSIDE triggers when a MOUSE_UP occurs outside of the object.

Comment: I think it has to do with displaying the ios status bar. When my finger goes over the status bar, the touch end is not being dispatched. Any ideas for getting around that?